# AppStoreConnect: App logo gets black/grey border

Tags: app-store, metadata, app-store-connect, mac-catalyst

When I upload my Catalyst app to AppStoreConnect it gets an additional black/grey border, which is also shown in AppStore after app acceptance, s. screenshot. The logo does NOT have this border.

The corresponding iOS App logo is OK. So I don't think the assets are corrupted.

Does anybody know how to avoid this ? It is annoying...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

The problem was that my asset catalog did only contain an icon named "App Store" with 1024x1024px. In earlier versions of Xcode/ASC this was sufficient.

Some time ago they changed the behaviour and you need also to provide icons  named "Mac" in different resolutions. If this is missing, ASC adds this border (for whatever reason).

Since my asset catalog was created years ago it did not contain the lately required new resolutions and that was the problem.